# PHP - Return an array from loop's value in a function

Tags: php, arrays, loops, return

For example, I have a function like this:

```
function loopValues()
{
    $a = array('a','b','c');
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        $c = $b.'e';
        echo $c;
    }
}
```

How could I return its value `aebece` in an array like `('ae','be','ce')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$a = array('a','b','c');
$b = array_map(function($ele) {
    return $ele .= 'e';
}, $a);
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dAWoyj)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function loopValues()
{
    $a = array('a','b','c');
    $result = array();
    foreach($a as $b){
        $result[] = $b.'e';
    }
    return $result;
}

$r = loopValues();
print_r($r);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/115578)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, try this:

```
function loopValues()
{
    $a = array('a','b','c');
    $r = array();
    foreach($a as $b)
    {
        $c = $b.'e';
        $r[] = $c;
    }
    return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function loopValues(){
   $a = array('a','b','c');
   for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
      $a[$i] .= 'e';
   }
   return $a;
}
```